# Loading an Array from Java Script into Web page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have included a fiddle here: [jsfiddle.net/LgE3N](http://jsfiddle.net/LgE3N)

I have a series of arrays in a javascript file that I need to import into an web page. I seem to be able to work with the arrays in the script and have been able to output totals of numbers into the page, however, I do not seem to be able to figure out how to print the entire list into the web page.

```
    window.onload = function ()
    {
$("#contributions").html (totalContributions.toFixed(2));
$("#amount").html (totalContributors);  

var dateString = "";
for (var j = 0; j < date.length; j++)
{
    dateString += date[j];
    $("#dateArray").html (dateString);
}
    }
```

.

```
    <div id="data_list">
    <table rules="rows" cellspacing='0'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>    
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
            <td>
                <p>dateArray</p>
                <id "dateArray">
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>amountArray</p>
            </td>
            <td>
```

Comment: I think you're missing some information.  What is "date"?  If you could make a Fiddle for this it would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: `<id "dateArray">` is not valid html. Change it to `<div id="dateArray"></div>`

Comment: when I use div id it puts the date beside the heading in the table. I want the dates to appear as a list underneath each of the headings.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what a Fiddle is. On I previous post I was told not to include all code. How much more would be helpful without overdoing it?

Comment: Go to jsfiddle.net and write your code there. Click the run button to show output. confirm correct output and click save/update. After it saves copy paste the link that gets created from the adress bar over here

Comment: hopefully this worked (I apologize for my lack of knowledge and clarity)   http://jsfiddle.net/LgE3N/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really hard, you need a loop that returns each row and append it to the table.

```
var count = firstName.length, sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sum += parseFloat(amount[i]);
    html = '<tr><td>'+ date[i] +'</td><td>'+ amount[i] +'</td><td>'+ firstName[i] +'</td><td>'+ lastName[i] +'</td><td><p>'+ street[i] +'<br>'+ city[i] +' '+ state[i] +' '+ zip[i] +'</p></td></tr>';
    $('#data').append(html);
};

$('#contributions').html(count);
$('#amount').html(sum);
```

DEMO: **http://jsfiddle.net/8XvQw/**